# How can I use my generated triggeres from sqlplus console into the oracle forms bulider?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I've created the following table:

```
create table Citizens_lic
(
No NUMBER(10) ,
ID NUMBER(10)   
constraint Citizens_ID_pk_1 PRIMARY KEY,
F_Name VARCHAR2(32) ,
M_Name VARCHAR2(32) ,
L_Name VARCHAR2(32) ,
DOB DATE ,
POF VARCHAR2(32) ,
GENDER VARCHAR2(32) ,
Soc_status VARCHAR2(32) ,
work_status VARCHAR2(32) ,
ISS_DATE date ,
EXP_Date date   
)
```

Then, I've generated some triggers 
for id, no, iss_date Exp_date 
from the sqlplus command as like the following pics

[image]

[image]

after that, all triggers work fine from the sqlplus command, all inserted values like id and no columns are generated itself **automatically** once a row is created

Now I want to show you where I got stuck!
I went to the oracle forms builder
I've made this form

[image]

and deleted all the ID, No, Iss_date, Exp_date item boxes because there's no need for it, each one must be already generated by a trigger.

then I ran it

[image]

unable to insert!

Now lets get it over the flow, anyone help :)

Comment: If you use the Display Error key or menu option, it should display the actual error that's causing that generic Oracle Forms error message. https://community.oracle.com/thread/863259?tstart=9479

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: :), understood Sir, #no_more_screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you have written four triggers for one event (well, strictly three triggers, because you have two scripts with the same trigger name but I assume that is just a cut'n'paste bloomer and you really intended the fourth script to create a trigger called `citizens_lic_trigg_4`). Another part of the problem is that you have two triggers populating `:new.no` and no trigger populating `:new.id`, which being the primary **must** be populated.

Four triggers firing on insert causes four times as much overhead as one trigger firing. So it's better to have just one trigger, for performance reasons. But it also makes it easier to avoid the errors in your code, because scanning one script is simpler than scanning four. Particularly when you're just editing the cached statement (`ed afiedt.buf`) so you can't eyeball all four scripts **(*)**.

So, a better implementation would be:

```
create or replace trigger citizens_lic_trigg
     before insert on citizens_lic
     for each row
begin
    /* or maybe these two assignments should be the other way round??? */
    :new.id := citizens_lic_seq_1.nextval;
    :new.no := round(dbms_random.value(1000500000,1099999999));
    :new.iss_date := sysdate;
    :new.exp_date := sysdate + (365*5);
end;
```

---

**(*)**  Unless you take a screenshot after each edit, as you have done here. But that's really inefficient: in the long run you will find it beneficial to have separate named files for each script, so you can save them in source control.

Answer (score 1):

two thoughts: both your triggers _1 and _2 insert into new.no. in your second screenshot you twice create the trigger _3. I'd say your problem is that you provide no value for your PK, the id. HTH